# How to start showing that a formula is valid

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

This is the problem on the practice exam for preparing the exam, this question seems impossible to solve, how to I get started guys? Appreciated for the tutoring in advance!

$\int\tan^n(x)dx=\dfrac{(tan^{n-1}(x))}{(n-1)}-\int\tan^{n-2}(x)dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that 
$$
\int\tan^n(x)dx+\int\tan^{n-2}(x)dx=\dfrac{(\tan^{n-1}(x))}{(n-1)},
$$
or
$$
\int\tan^n(x)+\tan^{n-2}(x)dx=\dfrac{(\tan^{n-1}(x))}{(n-1)}.
$$
In other words, the equality says that the derivative of the right-hand-side is $\tan^n(x)+\tan^{n-2}(x)$.

If you differentiate $\dfrac{(\tan^{n-1}(x))}{(n-1)}$ (you have to use the chain rule) you get
$$
\left(\dfrac{(\tan^{n-1}(x))}{(n-1)}\right)'=\frac1{n-1}\left((n-1)\tan^{n-2}(x)\times\tan'(x)\right)=\tan^{n-2}(x)\frac1{\cos^2(x)}\\=\tan^{n-2}(x)\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\tan^{n-2}(x)\,(\tan^2(x)+1)=\tan^n(x)+\tan^{n-2}(x).
$$

Comment: Well....you don't really have to give me the whole solution, thanks though for the tutor!